# Distorted line 2 in the sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list

Tags: apt, 18.04, software-sources

When I tried to install Apache in Ubuntu 18.04 using the command `sudo apt install apache2`, I got:

```
E: Distorted line 2 in the sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d  /official-package-repositories.list
E: The list of sources is not read.
E: Distorted line 2 in the sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
```

The second line contains the word `universe`. After I deleted it, I got:

```
The apache2 package is not available, but is listed in the dependency list of another package.
E: No installation candidate found for the “apache2” package.
```

Comment: Already tried :(

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` after editing your sources? If not, do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out line 2 in `//etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` by preceding that line with a # character. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
```

Comment out line 2.

The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Add the main repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` with nano text editor and add the following lines to it.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

If you get a duplicate entry in sources.list error about any of the 4 new lines that you added, you can open `/etc/apt/sources.list` again in nano text editor, and comment out the duplicate lines by preceding them with a #.

Update the list of available software and try to install apache2 again.

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install apache2
```